# Keep getting this code reparted again and again?

Tags: errors

I keep getting the code below above all my webpages and Dashboard.

It is repeating and I don’t know what to do. Any help please would be greatly appreciated thank you.

> nothing to repeat at offset 2 in
>   /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   2 in /home4/wwwcosta/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 219

Comment: i help you  and send solution

Comment: i add answer please try

Comment: Try disabling and enabling plugins one by one. Does this error disappear after disabling a certain plugin?

Comment: Did you try this solution https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-fix-wordpress-error-warning-preg_match-compilation-failed/?

Comment: Try this

 if ( preg_match("#^".preg_quote($match,'#'),"#", $request_match, $matches) ||
Note also remove the extra ) before ||

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the permalinks structure has an issue. 
Please follow below steps to fix it.

> Step 1: if possible, back up your WP installation folder. Step 2:
>   Temporary disable all the plugins (important step)
>
> step 3: in the WordPress admin dashboard, go to Settings -> Permalinks
>
> step 4: remember or note down somewhere what you have in the custom
>   permalinks
>
> step 5: temporarily enable (switch to) the default permalink:
>
> step 6: verify the website is working now (not everything, because the
>   plugins are disabled, but the preg_match error should be gone)
>
> step 7: switch back to the custom permalinks setting you had at step 3
>
> step 8: enable back all the plugins

The error will be gone.

[Reference link](https://forums.envato.com/t/error-warning-preg-match/77270/3)